# How to fix error while using DataParallel in GRU's network

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to do dataparallel into GRU's network as explained in the docs and I keep getting the same error

```
"""Defines the neural network, losss function and metrics"""

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, params, anchor_is_phrase):
        """
        Simple LSTM, used to generate the LSTM for both the word and video
        embeddings. 
        Args:
            params: (Params) contains vocab_size, embedding_dim, lstm_hidden_dim
            is_phrase: is word lstm or the vid lstm
        """
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        if anchor_is_phrase:
            self.lstm = nn.DataParallel(nn.GRU(params.word_embedding_dim, params.hidden_dim, 1)).cuda()#, batch_first=True)
        else:
            self.lstm = nn.DataParallel(nn.GRU(params.vid_embedding_dim, params.hidden_dim, 1)).cuda() #, batch_first=True)

    def forward(self, s, anchor_is_phrase = False):
        """
        Forward prop. 
        """
        s, _ = self.lstm(s)
        s.data.contiguous()
        return s
```

The error happens at line  s, _ = self.lstm(s) in the previous code :

```
 here:  s, _ = self.lstm(s)
        s.data.contiguous()
        return s
```

I get the following error message :

```
    s, _ = self.lstm(s)
  File "/home/pavelameen/miniconda3/envs/TD2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pavelameen/miniconda3/envs/TD2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 152, in forward
    outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
  File "/home/pavelameen/miniconda3/envs/TD2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 162, in parallel_apply
    return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
  File "/home/pavelameen/miniconda3/envs/TD2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 83, in parallel_apply
    raise output
  File "/home/pavelameen/miniconda3/envs/TD2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 59, in _worker
    output = module(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pavelameen/miniconda3/envs/TD2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pavelameen/miniconda3/envs/TD2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 193, in forward
    max_batch_size = input.size(0) if self.batch_first else input.size(1)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'
```

the interesting part is i try to output the type of s in line 27 and i get **PackedSequence** , why it convert to tuple in lstm forward method?

Answer (score 0):

`nn.GRU` [expects](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py) (line 181) either a [`PackedSequence`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/60c4e74e49770ca7204b812006926ac0778d30df/torch/nn/utils/rnn.py#L23) or a tesnor as input. As mentioned in the error, you are passing a tuple object `s` intead.

Comment: i printed the type of s before passing to the nn.GRU and i get PackedSequence !!!

Comment: This is strange, because you error is coming from a line which will only execute if input is not a `PackedSequence`. See line 181 to 191 in above link. Or you can look through the corresponding version of pytorch you are using.